# How to open all accounts records to users on the basis of specific field

Tags: sharing

In our organisation there are many roles like EastRep,West Rep,South Rep,North Rep.Account have many sharing rules on according to each region.

Now i want to open all accounts records to edit for users who have National in there region.Like 
**user.Region__c='National'.**

How can i implement it.

Comment: Does role Hierarchy make sense for your org? Have you tried to make a custom sharing rule? What issues are you having

Comment: Have you tried creating a National group and putting all national users in that group and created a sharing rule?

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:
Hi Arun,
    It's simple to open all account records to users on basis of specific field by using sharing rules.To implement it you can follow the steps below:
1) Go to sharing setting in your setup
2) Choose sObject as Account for field Manage Sharing Settings for
3)Create new Account Sharing Rule
4) In rule type select based on criteria field
5) Choose your field and condition.You can see the screenshot below for more clearer version:
[image]
NOTE: By this way you can edit one record at a time.To do a mass update to all the records you can follow any of the following ways. 
1) download all the data using data loader tool and then edit the CSV and upload the records back in Salesforce
2) Write a apex script and do mass update.
3) The answer to this question is filtering multiple account record but to mass edit it we will have to use the above methods.

Regards,
Ajay